# Create submenu in context menu

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, contextmenu

Is it possible to create submenu in context menu (right click menu) in Adobe Flex?

```
Menu1 >
  - Menu1.1
  - Menu1.2
Menu2 >
  - Menu2.1
  - Menu2.2
  - Menu2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

No; it is one of the current limitation; I believe of the Flash Player.

In Adobe AIR you can add submenus to the context menu using the submenu property of the [NativeMenuItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeMenuItem.html#submenu) class.

Comment: Hey, is there some update on this ?

has there been any changes to flash player that may support this now?

Comment: BUt if we need it in AIR can we achieve this one?

Comment: @Tahir Alvi You can create context menus in AIR the same way you do in Adobe Flex; but I do not believe there is a way to create cascading menus.

Comment: Thanks, I successfully do that looks at my post http://alvijee.blogspot.com/2011/09/flex-air-how-add-sub-menu-in-context.html

Comment: @Tahir Alvi Be sure to post that up as a formal answer.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to adding Sub-menu in AIR application

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="400"
         creationComplete="panel1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
         rightClick="panel1_rightClickHandler(event)" title="Context Menu with                         Subitem">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert
            private var myContextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            protected function panel1_creationCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                this.contextMenu = myContextMenu;
            }
            protected function panel1_rightClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var menuItem1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem('Menu 1');
                var menuItem2:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem('Menu 2');


                myContextMenu.customItems = [menuItem1, menuItem2 ];

                var subMenuItem1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem('Sub-  Menu 1');
                    subMenuItem1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemClick);

                var subMenuItem2:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem('Sub-   Menu 2');
                    subMenuItem2.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menuItemClick2);

                var myContextSubMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                myContextSubMenu.customItems = [subMenuItem1, subMenuItem2];

                menuItem1.submenu = myContextSubMenu;
            }
            protected function menuItemClick(event:Event):void
            {
                Alert.show('Sub-Menu 1 is clicked');
            }
            protected function menuItemClick2(event:Event):void
            {
                Alert.show('Sub-Menu 2 is clicked');
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Panel>
```

Enjoy