# creating submenu's in flex context menu

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu, submenu

Is there any workaround to create submenu in a flex context menu other than stopping right click from javascript.

Regards,

---

Hi Frank,

Yes, I want to create submenus in a context menu. Can you help me here.

Regards,

---

Hi Frank,

I need the context menu for the application not for datagrid.

In my initial question the phrase "other than stopping right click from javascript" means

"catch the right click in html, call a javascript function and over js call a as function."

The project that you have specified does the above procedure. I don't want to use this

procedure. Is there any other way for achieving submenus in a flex context menu. Could you

please tell me if so..

Regards,
Arvind

Comment: do you need the context menü for the application or for eg datagrid? In a Datagrid, i already implement a multilevel contextmenu.

Comment: Hi Frank,

I need the context menu for the application not for datagrid.

In my initial question the phrase "other than stopping right click from javascript" means

"catch the right click in html, call a javascript function and over js call a as function."

The project that you have specified does the above procedure. I don't want to use this

procedure. Is there any other way for achieving submenus in a flex context menu. Could you

please tell me if so..

Regards, Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

I don't know, what you exactly mean with this:

> other than stopping right click from
>   javascript.

But, if you want to create a entry in submenu, do this:

```
//Instance of my own class
private var myContext:myContextMenu = new myContextMenu();
application.contextMenu = myContext.myContextMenu;

//Here is the Class:
package com.my.components
{
    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///// My Context Menü /////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //to use:                                                                      //
    // private var myContext:MyContextMenu = new MyContextMenu();                  //
    // init() in creationComplete                                                  //
    // application.contextMenu = myContext.myContextMenu;                          //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */


    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.ContextMenuEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
    import flash.ui.ContextMenuBuiltInItems;
    import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;

    public class MyContextMenu extends Sprite
    {

        public var myContextMenu:ContextMenu;
        private var menuLabel:String = String.fromCharCode(169)+" My Company GmbH";

        public function MyContextMenu()
        {
            myContextMenu = new ContextMenu;
            removeDefaultItems();
            addCustomItems();
            myContextMenu.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT, menuSelectHandler);

            super();
        }

        private function removeDefaultItems():void
        {
            myContextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
            var defaultItems:ContextMenuBuiltInItems = myContextMenu.builtInItems;
            defaultItems.print = true;
        }

        private function addCustomItems():void
        {
            var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem(menuLabel);
            myContextMenu.customItems.push(item);
            item.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,menuItemSelectHandler);
        }

        private function menuSelectHandler(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
        {
        }

        private function menuItemSelectHandler(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
        {
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.my-company.de'));
        }

        private function createLabel():TextField
        {
            var txtField:TextField = new TextField();
            //txtField.text = textLabel;
            txtField.text = "RightClickHere";
            return txtField;
        }
    }
}
```

Have fun

*EDIT:*
There is an interesting project [here](http://code.google.com/p/custom-context-menu/). They catch the right click in html, call a javascript function and over js call a as function.

Unfortunately, the limitation of FP or NativeMenu APi allowed just on level contextmenu. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917682/create-submenu-in-context-menu)

Frank

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. My requirement is something like this.  Item1
     ->Item1a
     ->Item1b
     ->Item1c
Item2
     ->Item2a
     ->Item2b
     ->Item2c
Item3
     ->Item3a
     ->Item3b
     ->Item3c

Comment: @Arvind, if you have information you would like to add, please edit your original question, and not the answers of Frank. Cheers!

Comment: Arvid, you want to create submenus in a context menu? I'm not sure, it this is a rally good idea. But give me an answer, you want to create submenus in the contextmenu?